# Android apk permissions are missing

Tags: android, xamarin.android

My application is working well under debug mode on Sony Tablet 2. But when I built apk file and install application, all permissions are missing. It was said during installation that application doesn't require any permissions. I use Xamarin Studio. Here is my `AndroidManifest.xml`:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android" 
android:versionCode="1" android:versionName="1.0" 
package="com.hvzh.smsservice">
    <uses-sdk android:minSdkVersion="10" android:targetSdkVersion="24" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.SEND_SMS" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_CONTACTS" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_SMS" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_PHONE_STATE" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.RECEIVE_SMS" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.RECEIVE_MMS" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_CONTACTS" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_SOCIAL_STREAM" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_SMS" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_SETTINGS" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />
    <application android:allowBackup="true" android:icon="@mipmap/icon" 
android:label="@string/app_name"></application>
</manifest>
```

Comment: only Sony Tablet 2 having problem?

Comment: As of Android Marshmallow you have to request for permission per specific feature through code so just adding uses-permission tags won't work.

Comment: @sunita, at Lenovo Tab 3 the same situation

Comment: @J.Rahmati, thank You!

Comment: have you tried what J.Rahmati said? @Hermann

Comment: @sunita, not yet. I just installed release version of the application using adb

Comment: @sunita, I checked only permissions to write data to External Storage. Now it is working